# Precondition check failed error while updating Microsoft Dynamics CRM record

Tags: dynamics-crm, httprequest, odata, microsoft-dynamics

I am updating a MS Dynamics CRM record using HTTP Client from C# code. The code looks below.

```
string query = client.BaseAddress + <<url path>>;
JObject payload = new JObject
{
{"property name": "Property value"}
}

HttpContent content = new StringContent(payload.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PatchAsync(query, content, token);
```

When I am calling this, getting an error as "Precondition check failed. Status code: 412".

I have included headers to the request.

Could you please help to resolve this?

Regards

Comment: I have a few questions - why don't you use Xrm Tooling to perform operations with the data and the second one - did you try to run your request/payload in postman?